# Computing the quotient set on a equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused about how to calculate the quotient set and I can't really find any resources online. I have a set $N = \{1,2,...,9,10\}$ and $R \subseteq N\times N$ by $(a,b) R (x,y) \Longleftrightarrow a + y = b + x$.

How do you compute the quotient set $(N\times N)/R$?

Comment: There's something unclear about $R$. With this definition, it should be $R\subseteq (N\times N)\times(N\times N)$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $a-b = x-y$. Pairs are related if their difference is the same. How many differences are possible? What pairs satisfy the same distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a finite set, this can be quite mechanical. You're finding the set of equivalence classes, which are all sets of the form
$$[(a, b)] = \{(x, y) : (x, y) R (a, b)\}.$$
What you can do is just pick an element from $N \times N$, and find all the points that are equivalent to it under $R$. Once you have found this equivalence class, find another point in $N \times N$, not in the equivalence class found already, and do the process again. Then, pick another point not in either equivalence class, etc, etc, until you run out of points.

To start you off, let's consider $(2, 5)$. Which points $(x, y)$ are equivalent? We need
$$2 + y = 5 + x \iff y = 3 + x,$$
so the points are
$$[(2, 5)] = \{(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9), (7, 10)\}.$$
Now, choose a point not in this (e.g. $(3, 4)$), and do this again. Keep going until you exhaust all points (or maybe you'll find a pattern!).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! This is going to take forever to solve...lol

Comment: @GreenSaber You're welcome! As I said, you might find a pattern after doing some of these, which will make things easier. You'll still have to write out just as many sets, but you won't have to be so meticulous with computation.